# How to do Performance testing of a Content Delivery Network (CDN)

Tags: performance, cdn

Our current project involves testing of a CDN for a client . I was wondering if someone out there has already doen something like this and would help on how to go about it . I am actually looking at some test cases , tools (commercial as well as freeware) , what parameters to test etc  . The client is into Video on Demand Service and i am looking at tools which garner for streaming technologies .
any help is appreciated

Comment: http://www.cloudclimate.com/cdn-speed-test/ this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your client is in Video Content, so Video  Parameters should be included as part of your test

1. Jitter In Video
2. Start-up Latency for first user and subsequent user in a geography.
3. Video throughput.

   [This](http://www.keynote.com/solutions/web_performance/profile/testing-web-applications.html) can help. Also Cisco has an offerings on sniffing and measuring Multimedia performance over the web.

Comment: thanks neera .. any open source tool you know of which can be used to test streaming media ?